# Why th:field causes an error in Spring Boot and how to solve that?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, thymeleaf

I've designed a very dummy form with Java, Spring and MySQL aiming which takes name and mail variables as an input and post these variables into `user` MySQL table which also has two columns as name and email. However once I use `th:field` inside `form.html` that is the main html file in the template folder.

My dependencies are:

- Thymeleaf 2.5.5
- Spring JPA 2.5.5
- JDBC API 2.5.5
- Spring Web 2.5.5
- MySQL Driver 8.0.26

I've coded the `UserEntity.java` as follows:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
@Table(name="user")
public class UserEntity {
  @Id // stating it is the id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) // stating auto_increment feature
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  private String email;
  
  // getters and setters
```

UserRepository.java;

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

// This will be AUTO IMPLEMENTED by Spring into a Bean called userRepository
// CRUD refers Create, Read, Update, Delete

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Integer> {

}
```

AccessingDataMysqlApplication.java;

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AccessingDataMysqlApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AccessingDataMysqlApplication.class, args);
  }

}
```

UserController.java

```java
package com.example.demo;
 
import org.apache.catalina.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

import com.example.demo.UserEntity;
import com.example.demo.UserRepository; 


@Controller
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView welcome() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("form");
        return modelAndView;
    }  

    @Autowired private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @PostMapping("/add")
    @ResponseBody
    public String
    addNewUser(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String email)
    {
        UserEntity newUser = new UserEntity();
        newUser.setName(name);
        newUser.setEmail(email);
        userRepository.save(newUser);
        return "User Created";
    }
}
```

And finally `form.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/styles.css" media="screen">
    <title>Job Application Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Form</h1>

    <form th:action="@{/add}" 
          th:object="${user}"
          method="POST">
        
        <div>

            <div>Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" required></div>
            <div>Email: <input type="text" th:field="*{email}" required></div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"> <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what exactly is the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form expects a user-object (`th:object="${user}`) so you should provide this with the initial get-method

```java
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView welcome() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("form");
        modelAndView.addObject("user", new UserEntity()); // <----  
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

and the post-endpoint should handle the completed 'user'

```java
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public String addNewUser( UserEntity user, ....);
        ...
        userRepository.save(user);
        ...
    }
```

Have a look here [Bealdung spring-boot-crud-thymeleaf](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-crud-thymeleaf)

Comment: It solved the error yet now MySQL db receive data as ```mysql> select * from candidate;        
+----+-------+------+
| id | email | name |
+----+-------+------+
|  1 | NULL  | NULL |
|  2 | NULL  | NULL |
+----+-------+------+
```

Comment: Have you had a look the link? There is a reference to github with the used code, this should help.

Comment: The tutorial you provide is a perfect example